# Simplify formula with multiple IFS from the same column of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

All `IFS` are from the same range `CO4:CO53`, changing only the value to be searched, considering that there is only one range to search, is there any way to simplify it so that it doesn't get so big?

**It is noteworthy that all must be changed to the same value if found.**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
              IFERROR(
                      IFS(
                          CO4:CO53="Out","",
                          CO4:CO53="Mid","",
                          CO4:CO53="Early","",
                          CO4:CO53="Late","",
                          CO4:CO53="Red","",
                          CO4:CO53="Yellow","",
                          CO4:CO53="1","",
                          CO4:CO53="2","",
                          CO4:CO53="3","",
                          CO4:CO53="Disciplinary","",
                          CO4:CO53=1,"",
                          CO4:CO53=2,"",
                          CO4:CO53=3,""
                         ),
                      'Copy of Top Plantel A'!A2:A51
                     )
             )
```

Comment: Context might help, as we can't currently see what the formula is supposed to DO, what the full range of options is, etc. For instance, are the options shown 13 out of 25 possible answers? Or are they the ONLY acceptable answers? Is there a standard list of excluded values that is shorter than the list in the formula? Could Data Validation be used in place of a formula? The most efficient and effective way to get help is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it) with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment attached to the original post.

However, given only what I can see, you can try this method:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(CO4:CO53&"","^(Out|Mid|Early|Late|Red|Yellow|1|2|3|Disciplinary)$"),,'Copy of Top Plantel A'!A2:A51))`

`REGEXMATCH` returns `TRUE` (if a match is found) or `FALSE` if not.

The pipe symbol acts as `OR`.

A space is appended to `CO4:CO53` to convert the numbers 1, 2, 3 to strings (necessary for use with `REGEX`-type functions).

If the formula as written does not work as expected, please do share a link to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it), with permissions set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."